# Can Firefox support Remote Scripting?

Tags: firefox, scripting

We have a legacy Classic ASP application which makes use of Remote Scripting in a critical module to mimic AJAX (it was written before AJAX became a buzzword).  I would like to make Firefox the default browser for our company (most people here use IE; there's no software update services or GPOs defined here so any upgrading has to be a manual process - however it's not that bad as we're a tiny company of only 6 people), but I would like to know if there is any way to get Remote Scripting to work.  Right now when I try to access that module with Firefox I get an error stating `Cannot locate proxy which supports Remote Scripting`.

Is there any way around this or are we stuck with using IE for this module?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox support probably depends on exactly how Remote scripting is used, as the term encompasses various technologies.

As a quick solution, you could use [IETab](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1419) to embed IE into firefox for sites that need IE. This of course requires a working installation of IE on the system.

Other than that, you'll probably have to analyze the webapp to see what it does.

Comment: +1, IETab is just the thing for this!

Comment: IETab doesn't work on systems that don't have IE

Comment: @malfist: Yes, of course, I thought that would be obvious. Still can't hurt to mention it :-). Edited.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful to you:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20050514.asp